# Would the state Israel have been born without WWII?

Tags: israel

I know I´m finding myself on a very hypothetical slippery slope, but would the state of Israel have been born without WWII? Which is to say: did WWII function as a kind of catalyzer for the process of this birth? I know too little of the Jewish traditions, religion, holy books, etc. to answer this. Was the state Israel inevitable?

Comment: What kind of objective facts would convince you in one or another answer, given that this is a counterfactual question?

Comment: Also, what do you specifically mean by "born"? End of British Mandate? Declaration of Independence internally? Support/recognition by other governments?

Comment: While this has a political component to it this is not really about politics so much as history.  If you asked a question about the process that was involved it would be on topic, but this is really just calling for speculation about history.

Comment: The UK lost a lot of colonies in the second half of the 20th century, after WWII. Maybe the British mandate of Palestine would have been one of them, even if it weren't for the holocaust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Definitely, yes.

In modern history, the Jews have raised the question of establishing a sovereign Jewish state as early as in 1820's.

There have been quite a few [Proposals for a Jewish state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposals_for_a_Jewish_state), especially in 20th century; some have advanced further, while some happened to be less appealing.

The the revealed facts of Genocide of Jews in Nazi Germany have only sealed the world's decision to solve this problem after the victory.

So **yes**, the Jewish state would have been born sooner or later, considering consistent interest to the problem.
And **yes**, WWII became a catalyzer for this process.

There were several proposed *names* for the Jewish state, but if the question is about the nature of the Jewish state, not its name, the answer would be definitely positive.

Comment: I could counter-argue that because there were discussions about a Jewish state for over a hundred years before it happened, then it *wouldn't* have happened without WWII as a catalyst.  Which is why historical "what-if" questions like this aren't on topic here.

Comment: @Bobson I agree with this.